# Transform python dict to string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Given Python dict

```
x = {
  'x': '1',
  'y': '2',
  'z': '3',
}
```

What is the code to transform this to a string

```
x=1 y=2 z=3
```

Comment: `' '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in x.items())`

Comment: `' '.join('{0}={1}'.format(k, v) for k, v in your_dict.items())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = ' '.join(f'{key}={value}' for (key, value) in x.items())
```

oughta do the trick.

Careful with keys or values that contain spaces, though! :)